# Android spinner not selecting any item

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried to implement a spinner but i can't seem to get it to select an item, i can see the items in the drop down list but when i click on them the spinner stays blank

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/accountSpinner"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/test_list_item" />
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about the problem? Maybe posting some code from the Activity/Fragment where you are using the spinner and trying to make the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in string.xml:

```
<string-array name="spinner_values">
  <item>One</item>
  <item>Two</item>
  <item>Three</item>
</string-array>
```

Add this in your spinner:

```
<Spinner 
   ...
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_values"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement OnSelectedItem Listener interface like in the following snippet. Otherwise you only will have items listed that do nothing.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.accountSpinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        showToast("Spinner2: position=" + position + " id=" + id);
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        showToast("Spinner2: unselected");
                    }
                });
```

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/SpinnerItemSelectedListener.htm) just to get you started.